# Replace CSS url with Gulp task

Tags: html, css, gulp, gulp-rename

I try to replace the path of a CSS file in index.html using Gulp. The problem is I have multiple projects with different theme name, and the path of the source file is different in the distribution package

index.html

```
<link href="app/style/themes/dark/theme.css" id="hmi-theme" rel="stylesheet" />
```

In my distribution package, the theme is copied under something like *src\projects\project\app\style\themes*

dist/index.html

```
<link href="[set the path here/]app/style/themes/dark/theme.css" id="hmi-theme" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Here is an attempt with gulp-find to find the url in index.html:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var find = require('gulp-find');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('templates', function(){
    gulp.src(['index.html'])
        .pipe(find(/app\/style\/themes\/([^"]*)/g))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('file.txt'));
```

That works, I've got the value in the destination file. But is it possible to use this value with gulp-replace to change the value in the HTML file?

I've tried also something like:

```
.pipe(replace(/app\/style\/themes\/([^"]*)/g, "dist/" + find(/app\/style\/themes\/([^"]*)/g)))
```

But the value in index.html was:

```
dist/[object Object]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've finally found a solution:

```
return gulp.src(path.join(projectDir, 'index.html'))
  .pipe(replace(/app\/style\/themes\/([^"]*)/g, function(cssPath) {
      return "my-new-path/" + cssPath;
  } ))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(distDir));
```